# how to provide swagger.api.basepath dynamically in web.xml?

Tags: java, swagger

I am implementing swagger in my application to provide the documentation.
I configured the web.xml like this.

```
    <servlet-name>DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>api.version</param-name>
    <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>``
    <init-param>
    <param-name>swagger.api.title</param-name>
    <param-value>RESTful Webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
    <param-value>http://xyz:9080/rest/api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

But the issue is when am giving the full path then only i am getting "Try it out" option .when am giving the relative path like  "/rest/api" am not getting the  "Try it out" option.
Even I tried the config reader and custom Application (Using BeanConfig).
Nothing is working.Please give some solution .

Thanks in advance.